# How to get Push Segues, Containment controllers, and storyboards to work together

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm building an app with the following page flows (it's a big complex so I will try to be as clear as possible):

Login -> MainViewController

Now, MainViewController uses controller containment in iOS 5 to host two views/controllers:

```
   MainViewController
     /               \
FirstController    SecondController --> DetailsController
```

From SecondController, I want to segue to a separate View Controller (you can think of it as "details" if you think of MainViewController as "master").

From SecondController, I can segue using "modal" segue to DetailsController. But when I "pop" back, iOS reloads MainViewController. I don't want it to do that.

If I use "push" segue, I get a runtime error saying there are no UINavigationControllers on the stack. Fine.

So what I tried next was I tried to make MainViewController the root controller of a new UINavigationController:

```
  Login --> UINavigationController --> DetailsController (but "initiated" by Second)
                   |
            MainViewController
              /               \
      FirstController    SecondController
```

And then from SecondController, I tell UINavigationController to perform the "push" segue. But I still get the same runtime error - no UINavigationController found.

I must not understand how the navigation stack works - it's probably not checking the caller, because I'm sure I'm calling performSegueWithIdentifier: from the UINavigationController.

I was using the "Your second iOS app" as a guide, and they prescribe this method (modal segue). But I really do not want to re-load the MainViewController if at all possible (it's doing some expensive things). I would prefer iOS to "cache" my view/controller/data. I could of course write code to cache my data when I load the details page, and reload the cache instead of re-computing the data when I pop back, but I was hoping the "push" segue would do this for me automatically.

If you guys have any ideas, I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: When you say "pop back", are you actually using popViewController:animated:? Have you tried [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:] from DetailsController to get back to SecondController?

Comment: sorry - that's what I meant by "pop back" - dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:. It forces the "parent" view to reload.

Answer (score 0):

in order for the push to work, you need to select the view in IB that will make the call and embed it in a navigation controller from the editor menu.

editor > embed in> navigation controller

Comment: Hi - I have tried that. I made a SecondNavigationController which set as the root controller SecondController. I main MainViewController use SecondNavigationController (and verified it because the nav bar started showing up). But I still get the same exception when trying to use a push segue from SecondController.

Comment: I also checked that SecondController.navigationController is non-NULL, meaning it should be hosted correctly. I'm not sure why I still get an exception using a push segue.